# Is it possible to use shorthand for multiple tasks in same namespace in task requirements?

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

Here is an example Rakefile

```rb
namespace :install do
   task :baz do
       ...
   end

   task :quux do
       ...
   end
end

task :foo => ['bar:baz','bar:quux'] do
    ...
end
```

Is it possible to write something like `task :foo => ['bar' => ['baz', 'quux']] do`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done. I've just dug around in the source and if you must: checkout [resolve_args_with_dependencies](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/task_manager.rb#L95). In there you need to do horrible things to make this work. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You're one superhack monkeypatch away from making this happen, but I wouldn't advise it. This will create a non-standard dependency. If you can get a pull request approved, then hey, by all means.

Why don't you just make shorter aliases if you're fretting about things like this?

Comment: Well I don't really fret about the length, just the DRYness of my code :)

Comment: Since you're dealing with Ruby here, you could make a method that converts from your format into something that Rake can use. Example: `task :foo => x(:bar => %w[ baz quxx])` where `x(h)` would do the magic. Sometimes too much reductionism impairs understanding, though.